# Black Screen when opening Layout of Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-emulator

I followed [this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview#installation) to show my items in a recycler view. Only adaption I made was displaying them inside a Fragment instead of an Activity.
In my App i have a login screen which redirects the user to an Activity when pressing a button. The startup Screen works properly but when pressing the button (→ opening the activity and the fragment) all i get is a black screen. The Logcat output wont help either since it doesn't display any kind of errors. All i get is:

> I/ViewConfigCompat: Could not find method getScaledScrollFactor() on ViewConfiguration

This sounds more than a layout issue than a code issue or am I wrong here? Could this bug be caused by some error in the recycler view?

---

edit:

After a lot of debugging i could at least border the bug to occur when calling the ShopFragment Class/View. When setting the default Fragment to something else, it gets rendered. But once i enter the ShopFragment it becomes blank and freezes. So please be so kind and help me to find the bug:

ShopFragment:

```js
public class ShopFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    protected View mView;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;

    public ShopFragment() {
    }

    public static ShopFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ShopFragment fragment = new ShopFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //get reference to recyclerView
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop, container, false);
        this.mView = view;
        RecyclerView itemView = mView.findViewById(R.id.rvCategories);

        items = Item.ItemList();
        ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(items);
        itemView.setAdapter(adapter);
        itemView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));

        return view;
    }


    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

fragment_shop.xml:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvCategories"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Item:

```js
public class Item {

    private static ArrayList<Item> mItemList;
    private String mID, mTitle, mDescription, mProductType, mPictureLink, mCondition, mAvailability, mPrice, mBrand, mGtin, mMpn, mShippingCountry, mService, mShippingCosts, mpubDate;

    public Item() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mProductType;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Item> ItemList() {

        XMLHandler itemFetcher = new XMLHandler();
        itemFetcher.execute();

        while (itemFetcher.processing()) {
        }

        mItemList = itemFetcher.getItems();

        Log.i("ITEMS CONTENT", itemFetcher.getItems().toString());
        return itemFetcher.getItems();
    }
}
```

item_singleproduct.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

ItemAdapter

```js
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Item> mCategories;
    ViewHolder vh;

    public ItemAdapter(List<Item> categories) {
        mCategories = categories;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_singleproduct, parent, false);

        vh = new ViewHolder(contactView);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Item item = mCategories.get(position);

        TextView textView = vh.nameTextView;
        textView.setText(item.getmProductType());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCategories.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView nameTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your fragment code also.

Comment: Check whether R.id.fragmentplace is present in xml of activity_shop_main_view_screen or it is in xml of StartupScreen class.

Comment: It's located in activity_shop_main_view_screen.xml.

Comment: comment all lines of ShopFragment and just keep onCreate and onCreateView methods and check your code with debug. If getting same issue then there maybe issue in ShopMainViewScreen

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging like this

- Put your layout of fragment in a new parent
- Set wrapped layout visibility to GONE state
- Set parent layout color to yellow.

Try Changes:

- Change fragment parent layout to Frame Layout

Use Frame layout rather than

If you are able to see yellow color then start looking in the wrapped layout there may be some problem for sure.

Also Share some more code like recycler view Adapter's rows layout for better help.

Comment: still cant see any difference unfortunately.

Comment: Can you show me your layouts of activity, fragment and rows of adapter

Comment: Your activity layout

Answer (score 0):

1.Check import of Fragment of android.support.v4.app.Fragment
2.Use below code for replacing a fragment

```
private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment != null) {
       getSupportFragmentManager()
       .beginTransaction()
       .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
       .commit();
    }
    return false;
}
```

- May issue because of simple fragment and support fragment

Comment: the import is `import android.app.Fragment;`, is this a problem?
\e: Just saw that it is deprecated, i'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with following code:

```
if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
```

Make sure you are using OnFragmentInteractionListener interface properly in all fragment.